# Angular J resource get/find NOT WORKING

Tags: angularjs

I am wondering if there is an compatibility issue with my ngResource as no matter how hard I tried, I am unable to perform a get with an id parameter.

I have simplified the code down to:

```js
angular.module('loginMod',['ngResource']);
angular.
  module('loginMod').
  component('loginComp', {
   templateUrl: 'log-in/log-in.template.html',
 controller:  function LogInController($resource) {
  self = this;
  var person = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:4001/api/testusers/:uuid',{});
  self.findID = 2;
       //self.testUserSet = DBUsers.get();
       var oneUser = person.get({uuid: "2"});
       self.testVar = 20;
   }
  });
```

and the consistent error I get in the chrome browswer is:

```js
angular.min.js:118 TypeError: V is not a function
    at http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/shared/angular-resource.min.js:13:165
    at q (http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/shared/angular.min.js:7:449)
    at Object.setUrlParams (http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/shared/angular-resource.min.js:13:50)
    at Function.l.(anonymous function) [as get] (http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/shared/angular-resource.min.js:10:156)
    at new LogInController (http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/junk.js:40:29)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/shared/angular.min.js:41:456)
    at S.instance (http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/shared/angular.min.js:89:436)
    at p (http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/shared/angular.min.js:65:128)
    at http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/shared/angular.min.js:77:24
    at http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/shared/angular.min.js:131:20(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:118(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:90(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:131$eval @ angular.min.js:145$digest @ angular.min.js:142$apply @ angular.min.js:146l @ angular.min.js:97J @ angular.min.js:102t.onload @ angular.min.js:103
```

If I try the query() method it works fine, as does the get() method without an ID. Also, I know the API works for a single ID - I have tested this directly.Is it possible I'm using an ngResource file for a different version of angular???

Comment: The error occurs on the person.get line

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a compatibility issue.  I was using file versions of ngResource and angularjs, i.e.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="shared/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

But when I switched these over to get them directly from google apis, the problem disappeared:

```js
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-resource.js"></script>
```